# How do you check if a WordPress template file exist?

Tags: templates

Is there a native function to check if a theme a template file.  For instance, if a theme is not using the 'home.php' file, then execute some code...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I would add to the Answer the following:

```
function foo_function() {
    $located = locate_template( 'home.php' );
     if ( !empty( $located ) ) {
          // 'home.php' found in Theme, do something
     }
}
add_action('init', 'foo_function');
// remember to change both of the parameters above, first one for where you want the
// action to happen and the second one the name of the function declared
```

As @Chip Bennett, said it will check both `TEMPLATEPATH` and `STYLESHEETPATH`, but I would append the code to a hook instead of just putting it in the `functions.php` file.

But's up to you.

Comment: I'm gonna definitly use it with a hook.  I needed the function, because, i'm working on a options panel for my theme framework, that provide layout choices based on available templates.

Answer (score 9):

Any reason `locate_template()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)) wouldn't work?

```
if ( '' != locate_template( 'home.php' ) ) {
     // 'home.php' found in Theme, do something
}
```

Note that `locate_template()` will check both TEMPLATEPATH and STYLESHEETPATH, so it works for both a stand-alone Theme and a Child Theme.

Comment: Thanks Chip...much appreciated, i'm gonna give Webord the points, seems he needs it more then you :-P. Your awesome in this corner of Wordpress world. I've learned a lot from all your comments.